# Is it possible to Render a movie file as PNG and it's audio separately in blender?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I am planning to render an
Animation with sounds and character's voices lip sync but I don't want to render it at once as a movie file format (FFmpeg)  because I want to be able to pause it anytime.
So is there a way to render only the video file as PNG and then render only the audio with all the character's lip sync voices and sounds separately as an audio format and then edit and join the audio and PNG file to synchronize everything?

Comment: so you want to render each frame of your movie as a separate PNG image?

Comment: Images sequence does not render with audio, you could render your image sequences and then the audio (thoug is a better option to edit audio using a different program). After that you can use the Video sequencer to combine all and render as a video file

Comment: Of course. You can "Render Animation" (set the output as PNG) and "Render Audio". Both option located in the Render menu.

Comment: OK thanks so much. I'll try it